# WebSphere SIB vs MQ ? what is the best option to go for asynchronous messaging from within a J2EE application running on WebSphere?

Tags: performance, jms, websphere, scalability, ibm-mq

Requirement :Need to Handle web service request asynchronously.

My application is a EJB 3.0 Stateless Session Bean exposed as web service developed using RAD and deployed on a load balanced WebSphere 7.0 App Server .
It receives web service request and stores the message as Object in a Queue. Request will be processed asynchronously via MDB (Message Driven Bean) .

Two options exist:
1) WebSphere SIB
2) Websphere MQ

Is WebSphere SIB as good as MQ ? Are there any specific advantages of using MQ over SIB ? Since I'm using only Java and is there any advantages of MQ ? Note : it is a enterprise application and reliability / performance /scalability requirements need to be met.